# Jmeter authentication required issues

Tags: jmeter

Getting this pop-up, how to handle it?
[image]

This pop-up comes for all browsers. I try to solve this issue by using proxy user credentials use but the same issue gets reproduced.

I follow below steps:

1. Open CMD & run JMeter with user (jmeter -H 10.21....  -P 8080 -u username -a password)
2. Open JMeter and again same set HTTP authentication in ui and also not added some case .
3. Change proxy of browser and use 9090 & localhost.

   ### 4. Start JMeter proxy & try to creation script then that issue come.

Proxy server I used corporate server IP & port which are apply on the company network.

---

Please suggest what can I do? If I start normal GUI JMeter without cmd with username & password then connection gets refused.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching "Implementation" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Samplers to `Java`. It can be done via [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults) like

[image: HTTP Request Defaults Implementation]

If you face it during recording - it can be done under [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) -> HTTP Sampler Settings.

[image]

Comment: still have same issue

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.